# How to correct a screen wrapping around?

Tags: linux, display, graphics, centos-6

I got my hands on a Ubuntu System (which was displaying correctly) and I installed CentOS 6.3.
The screen is wrapping around on itself. Any ideas?

See for yourself

[image: Screenshot of the laptop]

Comment: a screenshot or photo would help loads here

Comment: Sorry, new user... :)

Comment: I read 'Laptop 15"' but still have to ask: Is it a built-in or an external display? If the latter applies, how is the display connected: digital (<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) or analog (<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector>)?

Comment: It is a built in LCD display.

Comment: xrandr recognizes it as LVDS1.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with CentOS 6.3 with a 19" Samsung monitor.

I solved this by changing the resolution in */System/Preferences/Display/* to 1280×720.

Comment: I don't get an option to change the resolution. It is stuck at 1366x768, which is the LCD's native resolution.